# Prove this improper integral is finite

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I tried to expand the term in the integral but it turns out to be of order 1/x and diverges...
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!
$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{\log (1+1/x^2)}dx<\infty?$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to expand it but it turned out to be of order 1/x and diverges..

Comment: @user49229 Edit that into the question.

Comment: You cannot prove it is finite because it is not, exactly for $$\sqrt{\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{x^2}\right)}\sim\frac{1}{x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This expression is good to check the integrability at $\infty$. For the integrability in 0, try to set $1/x^2=t$.